# Unable to connect database due to achive log Full

Tags: oracle11g

We have a oracle 11g database which was created some few months before. This database was working fine on port 1531. But 3 days back suddenly the database was unable to connect. We have diagnosed the issue and found that the archive logs were full. 
Since the Database is unable to connect, we cannot run the RMAN command to delete the archive log.

When we trying to connect this database, we get the following error :

> ORA-19815: WARNING: db_recovery_file_dest_size of 7516192768 bytes is
>   100.00 percent used, and has 0 remaining bytes available

The error file path is as follows

```
C:\app\Administrator\diag\rdbms\"DatabaseName"\"DatabaseName"\trace
```